# Adsense - put code after page load

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, adsense, document.write

Is it possible and allowed by Google to load Adsense code after page load? 
I store ads scripts in DB on my adserver (not only Adsense scripts) and privide my own adcodes.

What I'm planning to do is to get all my adcodes on $(document).ready(), create adserver requests queue from all these codes, then make requests one after another. Every request knows what scripts where returned before so I can prevent displaying 2 ads from the same provider. I'm planning to use writeCapture (https://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture) to avoid documet.wite problem but this doesn't seem to work with adsense with documet.write. 
Does anyone of you know how to solve this problem? Any writeCapture alternative that is not violating adsense policy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to try https://github.com/shenjunru/LazyWrite 
Just load it before your Google Adsense code.
Then run it on $(document).ready() or whenever you want like the demo does.

Comment: Does this work with nested document.write? For example: script1 documnt.writes script2 tag, which document.writes script3 tag etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Postscribe](https://github.com/krux/postscribe)

Here is an example

```
<div id="ad"><h5>Advertisement</h5></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // jQuery used as an example of delaying until load.
  $(function() {
    // Build url params and make the ad call
    postscribe('#ad', '<script src=doubleclick_url_with_params><\/script>');
  });
</script>
```